# React component is not using {this.state.something} at all

Tags: reactjs

The state is being declared properly as I can see when I console.log it but my Jumbotron component is not using it at all. Also, it is rending fine but the {this.state.name} is not being shown.

```
var React = require('react');
var TeamStore = require('../stores/TeamStore');
import Jumbotron from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Jumbotron';

function getTeamState() {
    return { name: TeamStore.getSelected() };
}

console.log(TeamStore.getSelected());

var TeamApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {getTeamState };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        TeamStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
                <Jumbotron>
                    <h1 style={{"marginLeft": "270px"}}>{this.state.name}</h1>   
                 </Jumbotron>

            )
    },

    _onChange: function() {
        this.setState(getTeamState());
    }
});

module.exports = TeamApp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't invoking `getTeamState` and you don't need the braces. Change it to this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return getTeamState();
},
```

Comment: I tried that initially but I kept getting this error: `TeamApp.getInitialState(): must return an object or null`

Comment: Nevermind, I take that back. when I tried it originally I forgot the parentheses